Calculate shape from WMS BBOX in projection
I want to write a little wms service in php, querying polygons from a mariadb database and use it with leaflet.
leaflet.js together with proj4leaflet.js calls my service with a BBOX parameter, supplying X and Y of the northwestern point and X and Y for the southeastern point.
Out of these two parameters, the wms service is supposed to calculate the shape that is to be covered by this call.
Usually, if the points in the coordinate system were in perfect 90 degree angles to each other, you could easily calcualte the area with these four points:
X1,Y1  X2,Y1  X2,Y2  X1,Y2

however, this does not account for the 'skew' of CRS:25832 and I end up having annoying gaps in my grid.
My next approach, was to find the northeast point mathematically, like so (pseudo)
DIST = DISTANCE(POINT(X1,Y1), POINT(X2,Y2)) / SQRT(2);
NE = POINT(X1 + DIST, Y2 + DIST)

(and doing the same for the southwestern point).
The resulting grid has way smaller gaps, but is still far from perfect.
How would I calculate the actual corner points of the diamond(?) shape of a map tile?
Ideally, this could be done entierly in sql, using virtual columns, but I guess I could live with a php solution.
Edit:
here are some picutes of my actual data, to illustrate my problem.
Squares 1,2,3 and 4 should line up perfectly, but don't.

On closer inspection, you see, that SE of 1 matches up with NW of 4 (pink), because these points get indicated by leaflet.

Points SW of 2 (purple) and NE of 3 (blue) should also be on the exact same position, but aren't.

some sample data and input and expected and actual results would go a long way toward making your question easier to follow

@ysth I added some screenshots to illustrate my problem. Hope they help

Why is this tagged with PHP and MariaDB?

@DarkBee Because these environments could be used to implement a solution to my problem. A solution using postgis, for example, would be no use to me. Feel free to edit the tags, if you don't think that this is how tags are supposed to be used.

.. Ok - And what have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck? SO is not a code-writing service

@DarkBee I have written that in the question.
What have I tried: to calculate the position of the two non-given points mathematically.
Where are you stuck: finding the right formula.

Have you verified that MariaDB or PHP handles projected coordinate system 25832?

Very confusing: Topic says you're looking for a bounding box, then later in your question you're looking for a diamond (polygon), which is totally different.

@RickJames they don't AFAIK, that's why I'm looking for a mathematical approach.

@GeorgRichter the wms standard (and thus leaflet when calling a wms service) use the BBOX parameter to indicate the bounds of the requested tile. Was I wrong in assuming the b stands for bounding then? I will edit the question, if this does indeed confuse readers.

@GeorgRichter I updated the question and title. Please let me know, if you find it more or less confusing now and/or edit the post yourself if you think you can improve the phrasing. I am a non-native speaker.

@LukasKroess - Is there are reason for using 25832 instead of 4326?

@RickJames yes - I have a large set of polygons that are all coded in 25832 that I have to incorporate with the wms. Also these polygons get updated periodically, so it's no use suggesting converting them all to 4326 a single time manually.

File a feature request with MariaDB.

perhaps just utilise MapServer PHP mapscript
